# Emacs: how to compile (run make) without pressing enter for the compile command query?

Tags: emacs, macros, makefile, xemacs

with (x)emacs, how could I run the 'compile' command without separately pressing enter to accept the default command? (I can bind the 'compile' to a key but I'd like the whole thing to happen without separate pressing of enter)

Of course, similar behaviour with some else command would also be ok.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I used to `(setq compilation-read-command nil)` in my `.emacs` and invoke `compile` with a prefix argument when I actually wanted to change the command line: `C-u M-x compile`

Since then, I found about the `recompile` command that's even closer to what I want.  Most importantly, it does not prompt for the command line.  This one is the command I actually bound to a function key.

The usual workflow then goes: `M-x compile` the first time per project, and `F9` at each iteration of the edit-compile-test process.

Comment: This has the advantage of allowing you to change the command occasionally, and then stick with the change.

Answer (score 9):

Hmm,

after still a little bit more googling, I found the answer from the [EmacsWiki : Compile command](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompileCommand) (under **No prompt for command**):

```
(setq compilation-read-command nil)
```

hope it helps somebody else later. No more pressing enter for the same default command.

Answer (score 8):

most obvious method is to call M-x recompile